# How to reset global variable on every new HTTP POST request?

Tags: node.js

We are actually tring to read a csv file as input and throw out the corresponding results for the data in CSV file.

For every new http POST request, new result is being appended to the existing data in array(productDetails), but I want to flush the old data in array for every new request.

```
let productDetails=[];

 router.get('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../','views','add-product.html'))
 })
 router.post('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{      
      if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
         return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
       }
      else {
         var sampleFile=req.files.file;
         sampleFile.mv('././uploads/'+sampleFile.name,function(err){
            if(err){
               return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
         })
         readFile('././uploads/'+sampleFile.name,'utf-8',(err,fileContent)=>{
            if(err){
               console.log(err); // Do something to handle the error or just throw it
               throw new Error(err);
            }
            const jsonObj = csvjson.toObject(fileContent);
            jsonObj.forEach(obj=>{
               data.forEach(obj1=>{
                  if(obj.Make ==obj1.Make && obj.Manufacture == obj1.Manufacture && obj.Product==obj1.Product){
                     productDetails.push({
                        product:obj1.Product,
                        price:obj1.Price,
                        manufacture:obj1.Manufacture,
                        make:obj1.Make
                     })

                  }
               }) 
            })


         })
      }
      res.redirect('/');
 })
exports.routes=router;
exports.productDetails=productDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try by adding this line

```
router.post('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{  
      productDetails=[];
      //YOUR CODE
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function variable rather than a global variable for producrDetails, so if you define your variable inside the `POST` call it will work according to your requirements and start will an empty `productDetails` array on every `POST` call.

```
router.post('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
     let productDetails=[]
     // CODE
     jsonObj.forEach(obj=>{
               data.forEach(obj1=>{
                  if(obj.Make ==obj1.Make && obj.Manufacture == obj1.Manufacture && obj.Product==obj1.Product){
                     productDetails.push({
                        product:obj1.Product,
                        price:obj1.Price,
                        manufacture:obj1.Manufacture,
                        make:obj1.Make
                     })

                  }
               }) 
            })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,but how do i export my function variable in .JS file so that i can use this productDetails array in another .JS file?